# How to use multiple .find() after selector in jquery chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector, chaining

Basically what the title says - I'm wondering if there's a way to use `.find()` on the same jQuery selector multiple times. Or maybe using `.find()` more than once isn't the right way to do this?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo">
    <h2>A Header</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#foo").find("h2").html("New header");
$("#foo").find("p").html("New text");
```

Webstorm complains about the duplicated jQuery selector. Is there a different/better way to do this?

Comment: `var f = $("#foo")`

Comment: You can use  `.end()` : `$("#foo").find("h2").html("New header").end().find("p").html("New text");` !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("#foo").find("h2").html("New header")
         .next("p").html("New Text");
```

Comment: That's probably more internally concise than my answer. Presumably, jQuery doesn't have to walk the tree from the document level for each element, as it would in mine.

Answer (score 7):

To go back to a previous collection in chaining, we can use [end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

```js
$("#foo")
    .find("h2")
        .html("New header")
        .end()
    .find("p")
        .html("New text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    <h2>A Header</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) to back to first selector after using `.find()` in chaining.

```js
$("#foo").find("h2").html("New header").addBack().find("p").html("New text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <h2>A Header</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just `.end()` you don't need to add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set :D

Answer (score 2):

The "right way" (the simplest way at least) is to use basic CSS selector syntax:

```
$("#foo h2").html("New header");
$("#foo p").html("New text");
```

Or more specifically, this:

```
$("#foo>h2").html("New header");
$("#foo>p").html("New text");
```

The first example targets any `h2` that is a descendant of `foo` at any level, whereas the second targets any `h2` that is an immediate descendant.

As for trying to do something like this:

```
x = $("#foo").find("h2").find("p");
```

This is equivalent to this:

```
x = $("#foo h2 p");
```

(You can verify this by going into debug after executing the statement and looking at `x.selector`.)  Which means that you are looking for a paragraph inside a header inside `foo`:

```
<div id="foo">
    <h2>A Header
        <p>**Selector would find this**</p>
    </h2>
</div>
```

And there isn't any such in your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="foo">
  <h2>A Header</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

var $foo = $("#foo");
$foo.find("h2").html("New header");
$foo.find("p").html("New text");
```

OR, if it's possible:

```
<div id="foo">
  <h2>A Header</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

var htmlString = '<h2>New header</h2><p>New text</p>';
$("#foo").html( htmlString );
```

Comment: That's rather a roundabout way to solve the problem.  Your `var $foo = $("#foo"); $foo.find("h2").html("New header");` is equivalent to `$("#foo h2").html("New header");`.

Comment: @BobRodes Using it like that caches the selected element. So, it does not need to find the element every time you select it using `$("#foo")`. It's considered a good practice to do so if you are going to use a selector multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I agree if you are going to reference a selected element multiple times (which the OP didn't mention), that you should store it in a variable. However, applying a `find` to the variable negates the advantage of caching, since you're appending a value to the existing selector and going and getting a new element all over again. You're incurring double overhead, once to cache the parent and once to get the descendant.  If you're going to avail yourself of caching to reference multiple elements of the same type, `var $foo_h2 =  $("#foo h2"); var $foo_b = $("#foo b")`, etc. makes more sense.

Comment: In any case, I think Sam Coles' answer is better than either of ours.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It says `duplicated jQuery selector` because you should ( when possible ) always cache your jQuery selectors, because it's wasteful calling `$("#foo")` each time you need that object.
So, your code should become like this

### HTML

```
<div id="foo">
  <h2>A Header</h2>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var foo = $("#foo");
foo.find("h2").html("New header");
foo.find("p").html("New text");
```